# How to choose $\delta' > 0$ for this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$
Let $a \in \dom f$, $\alpha > 1$ and suppose $\exists K> 0, \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall x \in V_{\delta}(c) \setminus c$,

$$|f(x) - f(c)| < K|x-c|^{\alpha}.$$

Show that $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Recall that
$$
\begin{matrix}
f \text{ is differentiable at } c \iff \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}} \dfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \text{ exists, say } f'(c) = L \\
\Updownarrow \\
\forall \varepsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \dom f, 0<|x-c|< \delta \implies \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - L\right| < \varepsilon.
\end{matrix}
$$

Here is my attempt:

*Proof.* Let $\varepsilon > 0$, pick $\delta'  = \min\{\delta , y \}$ (more details later about $y$) and suppose $0<|x-c|< \delta'$. Then

$$
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - L\right| & = |\frac{f(x) - f(c) - L|x-c|}{x-c}| \\
&= \frac{|f(x)-f(c)-L|x-c||}{|x-c|} \\
&\leq \frac{|f(x) - f(c)|}{|x-c|} + \frac{L|x-c|}{|x-c|} \\
&< \frac{K|x-c|^{\alpha}}{|x-c|} + |L| \\
&= K|x-c|^{\alpha - 1} + |L| \\
& < K(\delta')^{\alpha - 1} + |L|.
\end{split}
$$
Now I tried equating $K(\delta')^{\alpha - 1} + |L|$ to $\varepsilon$ and got
$$
\begin{split}
K(\delta')^{\alpha - 1} + |L| &= \varepsilon\\
K(\delta')^{\alpha - 1} &= \varepsilon - |L|\\
(\delta')^{\alpha - 1} &= \frac{\varepsilon - |L|}{K}\\
\delta' &= \left(\frac{\varepsilon - |L|}{K}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha - 1}}.\\
\end{split}
$$
From this computation, how do I choose a correct $y > 0$ such that it guarantees $\delta' > 0$?

Thanks!

(Sorry for the typesetting, I'm still learning Latex.)

Comment: The inequality you used at the end of the second line makes it impossible for you to complete this argument. $|L|$ part should not be separated out.

Comment: I used the triangle inequality for that one

Comment: Are you required to use a $\delta$ argument? Because it seems sufficient that $|x-c|^{\alpha-1} \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$|f(x)-f(c)|\leq K|x-c|^{\alpha}\implies \frac{|f(x)-f(c)|}{|x-c|}\leq K|x-c|^{\alpha-1}\leq K\delta^{\alpha-1}$$
Which means the incremental ratio is bounded. But now, for $x\rightarrow c$ you have $|x-c|^{\alpha-1}\rightarrow 0$ as $\alpha-1>0$, thus by comparison you must have $\frac{|f(x)-f(c)|}{|x-c|}\rightarrow 0$ which means $f$ is differentiable with derivative $0$ on $c$.